# Robot Framework tests fail with "Firefox could not be found in the path!"

Tags: firefox, selenium, browser, path, robotframework

I use Robot Framework with Selenium Library. (Python27 and Firefox26).
Sometimes when I start a test it fails with:

Failed to start new browser session: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Firefox could not be found in the path!
Please add the directory containing ''firefox.exe'' to your PATH environment
variable, or explicitly specify a path to Firefox like this:
*firefox c:\blah\firefox.exe

It doesn't happen all the time so it's pretty strange. I checked the PATH environment variable and everything's fine with that.

Help please! Thank you!

Comment: Please show how are you initializing the test and how you are running a test. Have you already tried to specify *firefox explicitly?

Comment: I've tried like this: *firefox c:\Firefox\App\Firefox\firefox.exe. In this case I've got an invalide path exception. The solution is that you should add the path like this: *firefox /Firefox/App/Firefox/firefox.exe. But I still don't know why the environment variable is not enough..

Comment: If it doesn't work by explicitly specifying a path, check if specifying the directory structure to firefox.exe works. In your case it would be:
c:\Firefox\App\Firefox. Also, you might need to restart your PC for the changes to take effect.